# Need help understanding textbook solution

Tags: coding-theory

I am studying for my final exam in coding-theory class, and as [textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852336226) provides poorly written solution to the exercise question, I decided to ask the question here, hoping for more clarification.

**Question:**

> If $C_1$, $C_2 \subseteq V$ are linear codes, with generator matrices $G_1$, $G_2$
>   and parity-check matrices $H_1$, $H_2$, explain how to find a
>   generator matrix for $C_1 + C_2$ and a parity-check matrix for $C_1 \cap C_2$.

**Textbook solution:**

> Form a generator matrix $G$ for $C_1 + C_2$ by adjoining the rows of
>   $G_2$ to $G_1$ and then using elementary row operations to eliminate
>   linearly dependent rows. A similar process with the rows of $H_1$ and
>   $H_2$ gives a parity-check matrix $H$ for $C_1 \cap C_2$.

**Clarification:** My question is by word "adjoining", solution is referring to [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition) of two matrices or [adjudicating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) them. Also, what is definition of "linearly dependent row"? If you could provide an example, it would be great.

**Note:**
I really don't like asking this type of question but combination of unhelpful professor and awful textbook made me to do this.

Comment: I suspect that "adjoining" just means making a new matrix which has all the rows of $G_1$, followed by all the rows of $G_2$.

Comment: The question and answer (which is really only a hint) seem quite well put together to me. Maybe you should hold back on judgement on the book until you've become an expert yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to think of it that way. A code $C$, is just a subspace. A generator matrix is simply one basis of that subspace (i.e., each row is a basis element).

So in order to create the subspace $C_1+C_2$, you can take a basis of $C_1$ (for instance, the rows of its generator matrix), and add to it a basis of $C_2$. The new set is not a basis anymore, but if you eliminate dependencies it will be, and this new basis can be seen as the generator matrix of the new subspace (why?).

Same goes with $C_1 \cap C_2$. This subspace contains only elements which are **both** in $C_1$ and in $C_2$. Stated via  parity matrix, it contains only vectors that are in the kernel of $H_1$ and in the kernel of $H_2$. What happens if you build a matrix $H$ that contains both the rows of $H_1$ and of $H_2$? Which vectors will be in the kernel now?